# break and continue statements are causing finally block execution in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

I'm puzzled why `finally` is getting executed after `break`/`continue` (Version: Java 8 update 5)

```
testTryFinally();

function testTryFinally()
{
  try
  {
    print("Try 1");
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
      break;
    }  
    print("Try 2");
  }
  finally
  {
    print("Finally executed");
  }
}
```

Execution:
`.../tmp>jjs test.js`

Output with `break`:

```
Try 1
Finally executed
Try 2
Finally executed
```

Output with `continue` in place of `break`

```
Try 1
Finally executed
Finally executed
Try 2
Finally executed
```

I have tried executing the same code in browser (replacing `print()` with `console.log()`

Output is as expected in Firebug

```
Try 1
Try 2
Finally executed
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the relevant statement [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml):

> **. . .** While it's true `finally` will always be executed if defined, certain statements inside `try` such as `continue`, `break`, `return`, or when an error has occurred and there is no catch clause will all cause `finally` to be executed immediately thereafter **. . .**

But i don't see this is happening in Firefox (probably for a good reason)

Comment: +1 For months I have been wondering why the book "JavaScript---The Good Parts" completely ignores the existence of `finally`. Now I know why :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in Java 8u60 due out July 14, 2015
https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22937606